# How to load css first without refreshing page in angular

Tags: angular

I am making angular blog app in this app I am using angular image slider, I want to a fixed width of images when ng-deep using in this CSS code then its work but without refreshing the page the CSS is not loading.

blog.component.html

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <main role="main">
                    <div class="jumbotron" *ngFor="let user of usersBlog" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                        <h2 class="display-3">{{user.title}}</h2>
                        <angular-image-slider *ngIf="user.images" [images]="user.images"></angular-image-slider><br>

                        <p class="new22" style="display:-webkit-inline-flex;font-size: 14px" [innerHTML]="user.blog"></p>
                        <h4 class="ab1">Published By</h4>
                        <h6 class="ab2">{{user.first_name}}  {{user.last_name}}</h6>
                        <h6 class="ab2">{{user.created_at | date:'MM-dd-yyyy '}}</h6>

                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

blog.component.css

```
::ng-deep #grid[_ngcontent-c2] {
  margin-left: -189%;
  width: -170%;
}

::ng-deep.image-cropper[_ngcontent-c2] img[_ngcontent-c2]{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

In blog.component.css I am using this CSS on image slider.  In the first image, CSS is not worked when page refreshing and 2 images when page refreshing.[image]

[image]

Comment: Remove the `[_ngcontent-c2]` parts.

Comment: I am using this slider https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-image-slider then how to remove [_ngcontent-c2]

Comment: You select the text and press backspace on your keyboard. You are never supposed to be using those attributes for styling since they may change.

Comment: please like my question..@Chrillewoodz